# Skipping calculating average when no values are present. C++.Xcode

Tags: c++

I am calculating a function that calculates the average of scores in an array of structs. The function loops through an array and checks each item that has a value populated for the id parameter of the struct. For each of these items (where id !="") the denominator is incremented with 1
and the array sum variable is incremented with the value of the score parameter for that item in the array. The issue i face is when there are no items in the array and the function is called in printing an overall report. The avg becomes 0/0 which presents an error. I tried changing the denom start value to 1 so if the array is empty the calculation is 0/1=0, but this will definitely impact the actual average. Any idea how to tackle this?

```
double average(student o[])
{
    int arraySum =0, denom =0;
    double avg;

    for(int s=0; s<50 ; s++)
    {
        if(o[s].id !="")
        {
            arraySum+= o[s].score;
            denom+=1;
        }
    }

    avg = arraySum/denom;  //?? when the array is empty this is 0/0
    return avg;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `if` statement before you calculating the result

```
double average(student o[])
{
    int arraySum =0, denom =0;
    double avg;

    for(int s=0; s<50 ; s++)
    {
        if(o[s].id !="")
        {
            arraySum+= o[s].score;
            denom+=1;
        }
    }
    if(denom){
        avg = arraySum/denom;  //?? when the array is empty this is 0/0
        return avg;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks! should it just be if(denom) or if(denom >0){ avg=arraySum/denom; return avg;} else {return 0;}?

Comment: @asaber In `C/C++` `if (denom)` equals to `if(denom != 0)`. I like `if(denom)` cause it is shorter

Comment: This is an example of an approach which is convenient within the function, but does not give any consideration to needs of the caller.   Specifically, this solution provides no way for the caller to distinguish between an array with elements that average to zero, and an array with no elements.   If that distinction is important to the caller, then this solution is useless.

Comment: @Peter I agree, but what would be better? Passing a reference to `denom` (number of non empty ID) too or throwing an exception?

Comment: @Bob__   Answering that would start with reasoning about how the caller needs this function to behave.   This question started at the wrong point for such reasoning - inside the function.